# Mail client with support for gssapi

Tags: email, postfix, kerberos, gssapi

I have configured Postfix and Cyrus Imap to enable SSO using Kerberos and GSSAPI.

I use Thunderbird as a mail client which supports GSSAPI but I wanted to try some other client also.

I tried installing Opera Mail but this has no support.

That's another alternative to Thunderbird?, Know some Plug-in to add this functionality to mail clients?.

I do not have much experience in these matters.

I'll keep looking for information but I wanted to ask you to give a tip where I continue or indicate any alternative.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

Alpine and Mutt both have support for this kind of access.

Comment: And for Windows users which you recomendas me?.

Comment: In theory, you should be able to use Outlook for this kind of access. I've gone the other way and used GSSAPI to authenticate Alpine to Exchange, but I have no direct experience with windows email clients.